# Drupal7 multiple file upload or choose from existing files

Tags: drupal-7

I am new to Drupal and I know it have been asked previously but I cant get the solution for my problem.
I am creating an image gallery in Drupal 7.I have an Image field from which I want to able to upload multiple Images at once , or select from multiple existing images.
I have used multifile upload, but I can't reuse existing Images.
I used Media , I can select multiple existing files but can only upload a single Image at once.
Is there any way I can achieve what I want in Drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to upload multi images (files), download and enable [Multiupload Filefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget) and [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) modules. Then go to the content type `Manage fields` page, and choose `Multiupload` as a widget for your image field.

[image]

And for selecting from existing images, use [FileField Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources).
From the content type `Manage fields` page, click on `edit` next to the file field and check on `File sources` fieldset.

[image]

Comment: I can upload images using this module, but I can't choose existing images

Comment: Updated the answer with a screenshot, hope it's helpful now.